# QGIS Atlas: legend shows items outside map extent from next connected polygon

Tags: qgis, legend, atlas

I have created QGIS atlas with connected polygons but automatic legend is problematic. If I check option "Only show items in map extent" it still shows features outside map extent from the next polygon of coverage layer (see image). I can't check "Only show items inside current atlas feature" because some of features are outside coverage polygon. How can I solve this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Have you confirmed that your legend is linked to the map item in question (i.e. not another map item such as the overview, or to no map item at all)?

Comment: Thank you for response. Yes, the legend is linked to the right map. If all "dots" are inside current polygon and I check "Only show items inside current atlas feature", everything works fine. Problem is with items outside polygon and option "Only show items in map extent". Legend then "takes" items from all visible atlas polygon (for example: in map extent is only small empty corner of polygon but the legend "sees" it whole.